# Почему получается значение undefined

Tags: javascript, ооп

Вообще в идеале было бы классно чтобы это имело вид дерева, но я смог только так, при добавлении кафедры и препода в консоли значение undefined смотреть скрин, как исправить это? И если можно как то сделать в виде дерева подскажите пж.

[image: ошибка]

```
let mas = [];
class inst {
    name;
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class kafedra extends inst {
    namekaf;
    constructor(namekaf, name) {
        super(name);
        this.namekaf = namekaf;
    }
}

class prepod extends kafedra{
    lastname;
    rang;
    constructor(lastname, rang, namekaf, name) {
        super(namekaf, name);
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.rang = rang;
    }
}


function add() {
    let newinst = document.getElementById("add_instityt").value;
    const a = new inst(newinst);
    mas.push(a);
    console.log(mas);
}

function ll() {
    let newkaf = document.getElementById("add_kafedra").value;
    const b = new kafedra(newkaf);
    mas.push(b);
    console.log(mas);
}

function ee() {
    let newprep = document.getElementById("add_lastname").value;
    let newrang = document.getElementById("add_rang").value;
    const t = new prepod(newprep,newrang);
    mas.push(t);
    console.log(mas);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Конструкторы всех классов принимают параметры.

При этом, вызывая их с помощью `super` параметры не передаются.

Для решения достаточно их передавать:

```
constructor(namekaf, name) {
    super(name);

constructor(lastname, rang, namekaf, name) {
    super(namekaf, name);
```

---

Вторая часть проблемы заключается в неверном создании объектов, например:

```
const t = new prepod(newprep,newrang);
```

конструктор `prepod` принимает **4 параметра**, передается всего два, остальные становятся `undefined`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133448/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy----undefined).